# How to post long numerical data as input to code?

Tags: discussion

I have a problem in a function which manifest itself only at dealing with large numerical data. How I should post that numerical data, say a 100*100 real number array? Should I post the compressed text or should I link to an external site?

Comment: Does it manifest only with _that specific_ 100x100 matrix? Can `RandomReal[1, {100, 100}]` do or can you otherwise give the code to generate a representative matrix? If not, put it on a single line of code instead of breaking it up over several lines... this will also keep the post short visually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(From R.M.'s comment)

If the question is not depending on a particular matrix (e.g. the error appears with any random matrix), then please use a concise, implicit one-line definition, for example:

```
RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 100}]
```

and omit the huge numerical representation.

[`SeedRandom`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeedRandom.html) can be used to make the results reproducible.

Comment: And what if it's not random, eg often bug replication needs specific data.

Comment: @alancalvitti, in that case consider the answers to this question: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1351/45020.