# Upload large amount of data more easily

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Lately I came across [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/55761/2) with a huge amount of data which I put on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) [here](http://pastebin.com/S5ABeXHS) under [my](http://pastebin.com/u/Acquiesce) account.

One can see that I've already put quite a few *mathematica.stackexchange.com*-related set of data on *my Pastebin* with various lengths to ease the reading of some questions.

So I was wondering if it was possible to have a *mma.se* account for the community? Or maybe something like the [*imgur-palette*](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/can-i-easily-post-images-to-this-site-directly-from-mathematica-yes)?

Of course, it would be possible to upload them as guests, without an account, but at least with an account it's possible to edit/delete more easily.

Comment: I have a solution in the works (been working on it for sometime) but it isn't ready yet... I will release it here.

Comment: @rm-rf Any idea on when it could be released? Any details on the language used? Any help needed?

Comment: Hopefully within a month (depends on my free time)... python + sql + javascript.

Comment: @rm-rf We all look forward to it. :-)

Comment: I started experimenting on [this](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/633/193) some time ago. I don't remember why it went down on my pile ...

Comment: Now in v10 you can include unlimited data as *Metadata* [in images](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61456/10397), unfortunately **imgur** seems to strip images from the *EXIF* metadata. I wander if that's an option.

Answer (score 18):

Lest we forget, there is also a built-in way in V10 to share expressions with other users, namely `CloudPut` with `Permissions -> "Public"` and `CloudGet`:

[image: Sharing with the cloud]

Comment: Great idea in principle; I worry about the cost in WC credits.

Comment: @bobthechemist I'm not sure it uses any credits. Look at [this](http://www.wolfram.com/cloud-credits/) page; it only charges you for computation, not bandwidth. Storing/retrieving expressions does not require computation.

Comment: @bobthechemist I think this method won't cost any credit: [my test](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yuVRN.png).

Comment: @Silvia We mean this cloud object is used by others.

Answer (score 16):

This is a proof-of-concept using Pastebin. It's a utility function that you can put in your init.m to always have available in case you need to upload a list (or another string).

**How to install it**

1. Create a user account at [Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com).
2. Log in and copy your dev key from [this](http://pastebin.com/api) page.
3. Go to [this](http://pastebin.com/api/api_user_key.html) page and generate a user key.
4. Modify the function below with your own dev key and user key, and put the function where you want it (init.m for example.)

**Function**

```
Pastebin[expr_, OptionsPattern[{
    DevKey -> "<your dev key here>",
    UserKey -> "<your user key here>",
    PastePrivate -> "0",
    PasteName -> "",
    PasteExpireDate -> "N",
    }]] := With[{url = URLFetch[
     "http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php",
     "Method" -> "POST",
     "Parameters" -> {
       "api_option" -> "paste",
       "api_dev_key" -> OptionValue[DevKey],
       "api_user_key" -> OptionValue[UserKey],
       "api_paste_private" -> OptionValue[PastePrivate],
       "api_paste_name" -> OptionValue[PasteName],
       "api_paste_expire_date" -> OptionValue[PasteExpireDate],
       "api_paste_code" -> expr
       }
     ]},
    CopyToClipboard[
     StandardForm[
      Defer[Import][
      "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=" <> StringReplace[url, "http://pastebin.com/" -> ""]]
      ]
   ];
  Hyperlink[url]
  ]
```

**How to use it**

The only required argument is the string you want to upload. If the upload is successful a link is returned to the frontend and the corresponding `Import` statement is copied to the clipboard.

```
Pastebin[ToString@Range[10], PasteName -> "Test", PasteExpireDate -> "1W"]
(* Out: http://pastebin.com/postID *)
```

The clipboard now holds `Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=postID"]`.

There are are three options:

- **PastePrivate** `0` = *public*, `1` = *unlisted* and `2` = *private*
- **PasteExpireDate** `N` = *Never*, `10M` = *10 Minutes*, `1H` = *1 Hour*, `1D` = *1 Day*, `1W` = *1 Week*, `2W` = *2 Weeks*, `1M` = *1 Month*
- **PasteName** Each post can have a name.

**Screencast**

[image: screencast]

Comment: Unfortunatly `URLFetch` was introduced in _v9_. But, did you have that before? Or did you just make it?

Comment: @Öskå I just made it. At least I didn't use anything introduced in V10 :)

Comment: I was more or less thinking about doing the same (or that's how I would have imagined it) but since rm said that he had something in the works I gave up.. :)

Comment: Nice :) Could you perhaps set the default expiration to "Never" so that if someone just calls `Pastebin[code]`, we don't lose it in 10 mins?

Comment: @rm-rf Yep, done.

Comment: @rm-rf Do you think that it would be possible to have a common account for mma.se? Name could be something like _mma.se_ and password `Compress@"mma.se"`. Then `DevKey` and `UserKey` would be common for everyone.

Comment: @Pickett Then one person can know the password only. The point would be to have all the data under one account, and the keys for this account would be given in your answer here. Nobody needs to know the password after then `*Key` are given (or just one person).

Comment: @Öskå Sorry, I removed my comment because I didn't think it was well phrased. If you have the keys you can do anything you can do with the API, including deleting all posts on the account. You don't need the password.

Comment: @Pickett Ah. Then I don't know. Having all the pastes spread over multiple accounts is silly IMO, but maybe that's the only way.. :)

Comment: @Öskå On a closer look I think that if people use their own user keys we can share a developer key, because you can only delete posts associated with a user key. So would you prefer this? Also, do you have any other ideas for improvement?

Comment: @Pickett It's not about what I personally prefer or not.. :) It's just that there are currently several questions with pastebin links under different accounts or guests. And the problem is that I can't text your code because of `URLFetch` but it looks good from the Screencast.

Answer (score 13):

Not-so-large data can be QR-encoded in an image and uploaded to SE easily

```
dat = RandomInteger[9, {500, 3}];
BarcodeImage[Compress[dat], "QR"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
dat===Uncompress@BarcodeRecognize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/aulnt.png"]
> True
```

Not very efficient, I would agree, but simple enough.

Answer (score 3):

One needs to address two main issues first, before entertaining an answer

## Permanence

The main issue is find a method that will remain available permanently.

> *Unfortunately, we've had a lot of users share files on dropbox and*
> *then delete them at their end when they got the answer :(* –  **rm -rf**

## Minimalist policy

One should, in most cases, avoid large data or code, by providing a minimum working example, with code that generates simple synthetic data, if necessary. So try not to do this.

See also [Q2145](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2145/10397)

## Solutions

### HTML imbedded

[This Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/144472/10397) takes advantage of the fact that Mathematica Stack Exchange accepts HTML in the questions, invalid HTML is ignored when formatting the question for display, but still be available when editing the question.

You can format your data and paste at the end of your question.

```
EncodeForQuestion[expr_List] := 
 CopyToClipboard[
  StringJoin["<data payload=\"", 
    URLEncode[ExportString[expr, "CSV"]], "\"/>"]]
```

[image]

and get the data back with the API

```
GetQuestionPlain[SEQuestionId_Integer] := Import[
   URLBuild[
    {"https://api.stackexchange.com", "2.2", "posts", ToString[SEQuestionId]}
    , {"site" -> "mathematica", "filter" -> "!SWK9z)LGKmEEgF5)yL"}]
   , "RawJSON"][["items", 1, "body_markdown"]]
```

Be aware of [these safety considerations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/144171/10397)

### Data on [imgur](https://stack.imgur.com/) image

#### QR answer before.

As described in [this other answer](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1388/10397).

Answer (score 0):

### Using DropBox

```
data = RandomInteger[9, {1000, 3}];

dropbox = ServiceConnect["Dropbox", "New"];
ServiceExecute[dropbox
  ,"DataUpload"
  , {
    "Path" -> "/MmaSE/datatest.txt"
  , "Data" ->Compress[data]
   }
 ];
```

Now share manually in the DropBox page get the URL and change the option *"?dl=0"* to *"?dl=1"*

```
data == Uncompress[
 Import["https://www.dropbox.com/s/tofsut7k90m90pi/datatest.txt?dl=1", "Text"]
 ]
(* True *)
```

Unfortunately `dropbox["FileData", "Path" ->file]` does not provide the sharing link.

Comment: Unfortunately, we've had a lot of users share files on dropbox and then delete them at their end when they got the answer :(

Comment: @R.M. well things can be done wrongly on any platform. Pastebin.com could have expiration date, and data in Wolfram Could could be deleted too.

Comment: Fully agree, which is why I voted for your QR code approach :) May not be optimal, but at least it stays with the question.

Answer (score 0):

### paste.ee

https://paste.ee also offers permanent (never expire) paste with raw download.

```
pasteee[expr_, OptionsPattern[
   {
    "key" -> pasteekey (* Put your key string *)
    , "expire" -> "0"
    , "description" -> "Mma.SE"
    }]
  ] := Module[{
   import,
   id = URLFetch["https://paste.ee/api"
     , "Method" -> "POST"
     , "Parameters" ->
      {"key" -> OptionValue["key"]
       , "expire" -> OptionValue["expire"]
       , "description" -> OptionValue["description"]
       , "format" -> "simple"
       , "return" -> "id"
       , "paste" -> expr
       }]},
  import = StringJoin["Import[\"https://paste.ee/r/", id, "\"]"];
  CopyToClipboard@import;
  Echo[import, "Copied Clipboard: "];
  SystemOpen@StringJoin["https://paste.ee/p/", id];
  Row[{"Download file: ", URL[StringJoin["https://paste.ee/d/", id]]}]
  ]
```

Use

```
pasteee[
 "https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1351/10397"
 , "description" -> "Mma.meta.SE Q1351"
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]